# Android Opencv How to convert point to int?

Tags: android, opencv

I'd like to convert point to int

My code is Point

`Point zz = new Point(pt.y-radius,pt.y+radius);
 Point xx = new Point(pt.x-radius,pt.x+radius);`

Here is the code support int (not support Point).

`Mat rgba1 = rgba.submat(int a,int b,int c,int d);`

How to convert point to int ?

Thank you.

Comment: what is rgba ? what has this to do with opencv ? A Point is obviously not an int...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`submat()` takes rectangle points. And Point hold double pair (x,y)

Due to your specific points, I guest you should use next example:

```
Mat rgba1 = rgba.submat((int)zz.x, (int)zz.y, (int)xx.x, (int)xx.y);
```